# Using LTI-Lib in QT

Tags: c++, qt

How can I use [LTI-Lib](http://ltilib.sourceforge.net/doc/homepage/index.shtml) in QT?

Comment: it is a English forum not a Dutch one...

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be based on GTK+ 1.3 (old version) and not Qt. However, the wiki says that it is possible to build the library without those parts. To then display results using Qt, I guess that you will have to add some conversion routines yourself.